what the `cp --reflink=always` will do if I try to copy directory that contains reflink to a diffrent disk?
I have a folder root1 on disk partition sda1 which contain reflink/mnt/sda1/root1/a->/mnt/sda1/root1/raw/a
I have another folder root1 on disk partition sdb1, that has reflink /mnt/sdb1/root1/a->/mnt/sdb1/backup/raw/a.
sda1 and sdb1 has same file system. It can either both be XFS or both be btrfs
If I do copy -r --reflink=always /mnt/sda1/root1 /mnt/sdb1/root1.What will happen to my data?

case 1: the /mnt/sda1/root1/a and /mnt/sdb1/root1/a are exactly the same.
case 2: the /mnt/sda1/root1/a and /mnt/sdb1/root1/a are different in some blocks. but /mnt/sda1/root1/raw/a and /mnt/sdb1//backup/raw/a are the same.
case 3: all 4 a are different but most of the blocks are the same.

Is the copy smart enough to maintain the block sharing on the /sdb1?

Do reflinks across disks even make sense? Is this even possible? The man page for cp says --reflink=always will make cp fail if it isn't possible.

What stops you from just testing it out and checking the results? Most of the "what if..." questions are very easy to answer yourself by just performing the "if" and checking the "what".
